# Text or Medium Text MySQL Storing Delta from Quill JS

Tags: mysql, base64, quill

I am developing a blogging site using PHP and MySQL as server-side languages. The WYSIWYG Editor I choose for my site is "Quill JS". Quill is a cool editor with all the features I am looking for, it is also easy to customise. I am storing all the contents from Quill Editor, which is in delta format, into "Text" field of MySQL table. Text field has a storage capacity of about 65000 bytes which is more than enough for a blog article (Correct me if i'm wrong).

Now the problem that I am facing is that my blog article can contain pictures. Quill handles pictures by converting them to base64. A single image encoded in base64 format is at least 30000 characters. Now if I store base64 images in a "Text" field in MySQL my column is sure to run out of space.

So I found two solutions regarding the above problem. One was to create a custom image handler for Quill JS which uploads pictures to a server. And the second was to use "Medium Text" instead of "Text" field in MySQL. I am more inclined towards the second solution as it is easy to implement. But the problem is "Medium Text" has the capacity of around 16 million bytes which is certainly an overkill for a blog article. So if I use "Medium Text" over simple "Text" field in MySQL will there be any notable performance issues. And if the performance gets seriously affected then should I opt for first solution?

Comment: Why don't you store the images in a separate table as a BLOB? This way your `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s, and `DELETE`s will be transactional.

Comment: @TheImpaler That would mean extracting them from Quill's delta and then storing them in separate table an then again retrieving them and re-adjusting them within quill's delta ... This will make the solution unnecessarily complex. Instead of this its easy to store images directly into a server folder and add links into quill's image tag. But using Medium Text will make the process easier wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, storing it as a mediumtext would be the easier option.

Comment: @TheImpaler So the real question is that will mediumtext affect performance? If yes than how much?

Comment: Well... `TEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, `LONGTEXT` are all stored separately from the main table in another storage space already. The good news is that they don't allocate all max bytes, but only the space you use. This means it's optimal in terms of disk usage. Now, it will require two reads per row (main row + secondary `MEDIUMTEXT`), but it is already doing it since you are using `TEXT`. So it should be OK in terms of performance.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks alot ... this is what i was looking for